# Polar coordinates in dynamical systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

Using Polar coordinates, show that the system
\begin{align}
\dot x &= x -y -x(x^2 + y^2)   \\
\dot y &= x +y -y(4x^2 + y^2)
\end{align}

gives $\dot r = r - r^3 (1+\frac34 \sin^2(2\theta))$.

You are given that this system has a single fixed point located at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

I understand that
\begin{align}
r\dot r &= x\dot x + y\dot y   \\
&= x^2 -xy -x^2(x^2+y^2) +xy +y^2 -y^2(4x^2+y^2)  \\
&= x^2 + y^2 -x^2(x^2 +y^2) -y^2(4x^2+y^2)  \\
&= x^2 + y^2 -x^4 -y^4 -5x^2y^2.
\end{align}

However, I cannot understand the final step to the answer.

It follows after this to find radii $r_1 < r_2$ such that $\dot r > 0$ for $r < r_1$ and $\dot r < 0$ for $r > r_2$. How does one go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Adding

$$
x\dot{x} = x^2 - x y -x^2(x^{2} + y^{2})\\
y\dot{y} = y x + y^2 -y^2(4x^{2} + y^{2})
$$

we obtain

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2) = x^2+y^2-x^2(x^{2} + y^{2})-y^2(4x^{2} + y^{2})
$$

substituting now

$$
x = r \cos\theta\\
y = r \sin\theta
$$

we obtain

$$
\dot r = r-(1+\frac 34\sin^2(2\theta))r^3
$$

so we have an isolated unstable equilibrium point at $r=0$ and an stable limit cycle as can be depicted in the attached figure

[image]